# Primefaces: Lightbox change image height

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lightbox

When I set in lightbox a special height for example 100px or 100% the overlay image are not expanded. It's also not possible to do this with css. With javascript it is not so easy to build a workaround (still in progress).
Is anybody able to set a height in any way in the lightbox component? I use lightbox on many not jsf pages where it works perfect.

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="eintragFullscreen" height="100px" rendered="#{eintragPublic.hasImage}">
    <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/images/image?id=#{eintragPublic.eintrag.id}">
        <h:graphicImage
            value="/images/image?id=#{eintragPublic.eintrag.id}"
            styleClass="img_eintrag" />
    </h:outputLink>
</p:lightBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify thumbnail height and overlay height like this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet>
    .thumb {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .view {
        height: 500px;
    }
</h:outputStylesheet>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p:lightBox styleClass="view">
        <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/img.png">
            <h:graphicImage styleClass="thumb" value="/resources/img.png" />
        </h:outputLink>
    </p:lightBox>
</h:body>
</html>
```

For some reason thumbnail height affects overlay height, so both heights have to specified explicitly.

The `height` of `p:lightbox` specifies overlay height only in inframe mode, see [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation).